# geoxml3 and placemarks not functioning

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

Well I've read through and tried to find out the solutions but fail...

I followed the instructions from the geoxmlv3: http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/Usage

here is a quote from that document:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({afterParse: useTheData});
    myParser.parse('my_geodata.kml');

    function useTheData(doc) {
      // Geodata handling goes here, using JSON properties of the doc object
      for (var i = 0; i < doc.placemarks.length; i++) {
        doSomething;
      }
    };
  </script>
```

According to the documentation, the doc.placemarks should be working and return an array of json of placemarks in the KML file, unfortunately this 'doc' doesn't even exist(undefined), any idea?

Comment: [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) and [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) are two different things, looks like you are asking about geoxml3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the poly branch, "doc" is an array.

```
function useTheData(doc) {
  // Geodata handling goes here, using JSON properties of the doc object
  for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].placemarks.length; i++) {
    doSomething;
  }
};
```

I will fix the example in the documentation.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_simpleExample.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use KmlLayer of Google Maps API v3?
It's easy to map information from KML file onto the map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers

Comment: The reason why I do so is because I need to retrieve data from KML. If I am not wrong, the map api doesn't support to retrieve any data from placemark unless you 'click' or interact with the markers. I want to place labels with the markers, but I don't know the best way to do it.